# Drools - forall from accumulate not working

Tags: java, drools

I have this class hierarchy:

```
DomainParent{List<Details>, Boolean isCalculatedTypes(defaults false)}
Detail{List<SubDetail>}
SubDetail{TypeEnum}
```

And this Enum:

```
TypeEnum{Type1, Type2, Type3}
```

I want to create a drools rule that checks if all the SubDetails has **either Type1 or Type2** and another rule that triggers if the SubDetails list contains any different combination of Type.

So far I have this rule, which gets executed no matter what, even if all the SubDetails has Type3:

```
rule "calculate sub details with types 1 and 2"
    when
      $parent: DomainParent(!isCalculatedTypes())
      $subDetails: List() from accumulate($detail: Detail() from $parent.getDetails();
                          collectList($detail.getSubDetails()))
      forall(SubDetail(getTypeEnum() == TypeEnum.1() || getTypeEnum() == TypeEnum.2() from $subDetails)
    then
      System.out.println("begin calculating types");
      //DO SOMETHING
      $parent.setCalculatedTypes(true);
      update($parent);
      System.out.println("DONE calculating types");
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your rule to calculate a flattened List of SubDetail objects.

```
rule "calculate sub details with types 1 and 2"
when
  $dp: DomainParent( ! calculatedTypes, $details: details )
  $sds: List( size > 0 ) 
    from accumulate( $detail: Detail() from $details,
                     init( List list = new ArrayList(); )
                     action(list.addAll($detail.getSubDetails()); )
                     result( list ) )
  not( SubDetail( type != Type.Type1 && != Type.Type2 ) from $sds )
then
  System.out.println("begin calculating types");
end
```

The mistake you have made is to believe that adding a 
`List<X>` to a list adds all X's in that list but it does not: it just adds a List to the list.

Note that `forall` is tricky and does not what (I think that) you think.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you managed to refer to your enum this way: `TypeEnum.1()`;
Try this instead:

```
rule "calculate sub details with types 1 and 2"
    when
      $parent: DomainParent(!isCalculatedTypes())
      $subDetails: List() from accumulate($detail: Detail() from $parent.getDetails();
                          collectList($detail.getSubDetails()))
      forall($x : SubDetail(getTypeEnum() == TypeEnum.Type1 || getTypeEnum() == TypeEnum.Type2)
    then
      //DO SOMETHING
end
```

Comment: While your objection is certainly valid, this does not address OP's problem at all. You might make this a comment.